# Why are Chinese Traditional (Big 5) fonts served up by Apache garbled?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, redhat

In migrating an Apache web site from RHEL 5 to CentOS 5 I noticed Chinese Traditional (Big 5) fonts look fine on the old site, but are garbled on the new site.

In Firefox, I can get the fonts to display properly by clicking View -> Character Encoding -> and changing "Unicode (UTF-8" to "Chinese Traditional (Big 5)".

How can I tell Apache to set the character encoding properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default CentOS 5.5 installation, Apache is configured with the [AddDefaultCharset Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset) set to "UTF-8".  Commenting it out and restarting Apache fixed the problem:

```
[root@cbdb ~]# cd /etc/httpd/conf
[root@cbdb conf]# cp -a httpd.conf httpd.conf.orig
[root@cbdb conf]# vi httpd.conf
[root@cbdb conf]# diff httpd.conf.orig httpd.conf
747c747
< AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
---
> #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
[root@cbdb conf]# service httpd restart
```